# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I was learning webdriver and stuff.

I tried below code:

```
import random, time, requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

But getting an error as below:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
>   geckodriver  unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup GeckoDriver properly? You need to provide the GeckoDriver location in System properties, as well as Firefox binary if you are using the latest versions.

Please check out this article for setup. The code snippets are in Java though.

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/